# Listbox/listview vertical scrollbar does not show (horizontal yes)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listbox, scrollbar

I've a listbox defined in xaml like this:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="21" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="23" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="23" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="23" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="26" />
  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  <RowDefinition Height="4" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>


<ListBox x:Name="AInLb" Margin="8,6,8,8" BorderBrush="Gray" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Content.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/> 
      <Setter Property="Template"> 
        <Setter.Value> 
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem"> 
            <ContentPresenter/> 
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value> 
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ListView x:Name="AInfoLv" FontFamily="Khmer UI" Background="White" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Black">
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn x:Name="LabelColumn" Header="Label" Width="110" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Label}" />
        <GridViewColumn x:Name="ValueColumn" Header="Value" Width="140" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" />
      </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value> 
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
              <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <GridViewRowPresenter/> 
              </Border>
            </ControlTemplate> 
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter> 
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Label}" Value="Login"> 
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/> 
          </DataTrigger> 
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Label}" Value="Skill(s)">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/> 
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ListView>
</ListBox>
```

The height and width for both listbox and listview are set to auto. When the content exceeded the height and width of the listbox, the horizontal scrollbar works fine, but the vertical scrollbar does not show.

[image]

**Update:**
Included @Dom's suggestion.

[image]

**Update 2:**
After `Height` limit is set for the `listbox`.

[image]

Comment: `ListBox` does not restrict its items height if vertical scroll is enabled so your `ListView` item can grow as high as it needs to to accommodate all items therefore you'll never see scroll bar on your `ListView` item. Why scroll bar does not appear on `ListBox`  is different question. It seems that somewhere up the visual tree (one of `ListBox` parents) is another panel that does not restrict its children height like `StackPanel` or `Canvas`

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved by setting `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` for the `ListBox`. [Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/174783/WPF-ListBox-scrollbar-problem).

Answer (score 0):

The ListView alreas a ScrollViewer. You need to enable it:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
 Scro
```

Comment: Hi @Dom, thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't work for me.